# Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js

I am very frustrated with this frustrated npm issue
When i try to run a project with npm modules Node.Js, React, NextJs i get this error
this is the terminal output;

```
npm ERR! path C:\...\NextJs_project\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\NextJs_project\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

What can i do?

'npm run dev' and 'npm install' also give the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to run the commands in the wrong directory.

use `ls` to list the files in the current directory. If you can't see the package.json file, that's the issue.

Open a terminal in the project directory and try again.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. Btw previously the "npx create-react-app" command already working the folder has been created. Was i wrong?

Comment: I assume you might have create-react-app installed globally.